# Two connected non homeomorphic spaces on $\mathbb{R}$ with continuous and bijective $f,g$

Tags: general-topology

Consider a $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}$. We know that there are exist continuous, bijective $f : X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$. 
I found an example of non-homeomorphic and **disconnected** $X$ and $Y$ ( collection of open intervals and points , and collections of intervals and semi interval).
But my teacher told that there is example of connected $X$ and $Y$ according to this properties. Also he said that it's possible to upgrade a standard counterexample with disjoint intervals. Any ideas ?

I thought to consider intervals $(a, + \inf)$ instead of $(i,i+1)$ and upgrade topology on $\mathbb{R}$. But don't know how to construct it.

Comment: I'm confused, your second sentence is false (unless it's an assumption?) Are you looking for examples of large non-homeomorphic subsets of $\mathbb R$ which satisfy that statement?

Comment: @NotMike I guess there is no connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are not homeomorphic and there are exist such $f,g$

Comment: @NotMike actually yes I'm looking for such subsets. But I don't know about connected examples. (X and Y must me connected)

Comment: I think the OP's question is as follows: How can I find two connected subspaces $X$ and $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic but, nonetheless, there are continuous bijections $f:X \to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such spaces.  A connected subspace of the real line is an interval or a point.  Suppose $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}$ are connected subspaces.  If $X$ is compact and $f:X \to Y$ is a bijection, then it is a homeomorphism (since $Y$ is Hausdorff).  Half-open intervals are homeomorphic.  Open intervals are homeomorphic.  So, the only remaining possibility (up to reordering and homeomorphism) is that $X = [0,1)$ and $Y = (0,1)$.  But a bijection $f:X \to Y$ must have the property that either $(0,f(0))$ is not in the image or $(f(0),1)$ is not in the image.

Comment: Does it depend of topology?

Comment: Yes.  If you change the topology on $\mathbb{R}$, then the classification of connected subspaces is probably no longer true.  Are you asking if there is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ with this property?

Comment: I'm asking does there some example on $\mathbb{R}$ with this properties. I didn't mentioned about topology. I guess that will help us to construct an example. Because I understand if $X$ and $Y$ are connected topological spaces with standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ then either they homeomorphic or there is no such bijections.

Comment: @openspace in your question, when you say non-homeomorphic, do you actually mean, not order-isomorphic? Moreover, by disconnected, did you mean has isolated points?

Comment: @NotMike wiki says : "connected space is a topological space that cannot be represented as the union of two or more disjoint nonempty open subsets"

Comment: @NotMike so disconnected is union of disjoint sets. So in standard topology this is union of intervals f.e.

Comment: @openspace I'm aware of this. However, had you said yes, I would have pointed out that  under certain additional set theoretic assumptions, the structure of $\aleph_1$-dense sets of reals is not so clear cut.

Comment: @NotMike that is a problem I don't know how to start with